# How can I get request string URL that sent to robospice retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, robospice

I searched but did not find a helpful information. Trying to deal with the REST API Client, I am use robospice in conjunction with retofit, I want to look at the request string that is sent to the service. Is it possible to pull an entire string URL from Robospice or Retrofit?

Here is my interface:

```
public interface GoogleSearchInterface {
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch";
public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCCuxxVLzm2sZP-adhRNYKeSck1mMMgsAM";
public static final String CUSTOM_SEARCH_ID = "001734592082236324715:sob9rqk49yg";
public static final String SEARCH_TYPE_IMAGE = "image";
static final String FILTER = "&fields=queries(nextPage(startIndex,count),request(startIndex,count)),searchInformation(totalResults),items(title,link,displayLink,mime," +
        "image)";
static final String QUERY = "/v1?key="+API_KEY+
                            "&cx="+CUSTOM_SEARCH_ID+
                            "&searchType="+SEARCH_TYPE_IMAGE+FILTER;

@GET(QUERY)
public GoogleSearchResponse search(@Query("q") String query,
                                   @Query("start") long startIndex);
@GET(QUERY)
public GoogleSearchResponse search(@Query("q") String query,
                                   @Query("start") long startIndex,
                                   @Query("searchType") String searchType,
                                   @Query("limit") String limit,
                                   @Query("offset") String offset);
```

SpiceRequest

```
 String query;
long startIndex;
String limit;
String offset;

public SampleRetrofitSpiceRequest(String query,long startIndex,String limit,String offset) {
    super(GoogleSearchResponse.class,GoogleSearchInterface.class);
    this.query = query;
    this.startIndex = startIndex;
    this.limit=limit;
    this.offset=offset;
}

public SampleRetrofitSpiceRequest(String query, long startIndex) {
    super(GoogleSearchResponse.class, GoogleSearchInterface.class);
    this.query = query;
    this.startIndex = startIndex;
}
@Override
public GoogleSearchResponse loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    return getService().search(query,startIndex);
}
```

SpiceService

```
public class SampleRetrofitSpiceService extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    addRetrofitInterface(GoogleSearchInterface.class);
}

@Override
protected String getServerUrl() {
    return GoogleSearchInterface.BASE_URL;
}
```

Method which send request

```
 public void sendRequest(String query,int page){
    searchQuery = query;
    request = new SampleRetrofitSpiceRequest(query, page);
   spiceManager.execute(request, query, DurationInMillis.ONE_WEEK, new RequestImageListener());
 /*   try {
        spiceManager.getFromCache(GoogleSearchResponse.class, "country",DurationInMillis.ONE_WEEK,new RequestImageListener());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    request=null;
}
```

P.S. I'm writing an application that will make image search, first 10 result successfully loading but next page is repeating previous page. I fight with this lot of time, &start parameter of google api that sent in spiceRequst is ignored. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to override this method in *custom SpiceService.class*

```
 @Override
protected RestAdapter.Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
            .setConverter(getConverter())
            .setEndpoint(getServerUrl());
    return builder;
}
```